# Google analytics enhanced ecommerce: order of checkout steps

Tags: google-analytics

I really cant find the answer in official Google documentation:

1. Is it acceptable to send ec:checkout_option for **previous** step and the **next checkout step** on one event?

What for:

If user have choosen an delivery method and pressed "continue" - I want to set checkout_option for step 2 and checkout-action for step 3 and send them in one event;

```
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout_option', {'step': 2,'option':paymentName});
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {'step': 3});
ga('send', 'event', 'Checkout')
```

If 'yes' - then next question:

2. Is it acceptable to send ec:checkout_option for **previous** step **after** the **next checkout step** event has been **set**?

What for:

Nearly the same case, but do I really must keep an order of those ec:setAction calls before sending a beacon? In other words, could I apply such calls sequence?

```
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {'step': 3});
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout_option', {'step': 2,'option':paymentName});
ga('send', 'event', 'Checkout')
```

3. Go deeper: Is it acceptable to send ec:checkout_option for **previous** step **after** the **next checkout step** event has been **SENT**?

What for?

user chenged his mind and choosen another option (lets imagine that all checkout is in one step and user can change earlier data **without explicit returning to previous step**.

```
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {'step': 3});
ga('send', 'event', 'Checkout')

ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout_option', {'step': 2,'option':paymentName});
ga('send', 'event', 'Checkout')
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can do that. You can send the `check_option` for previous step after the next checkout step event has been set. Before ga send the events, they collect all `ec:setAction` and then send all the information at same time.
2. Yes, the actions order has no relevace.
3. If the checkout is in one page and the user can change some previous data, you can send only the `checkout_option` with the new option value and google will update the previous value.

I have a checkout process all in one page and it has 8 steps. I recommend to write separated functions" one for `checkout` and one for `checkout_option` and call it when you need. It would be something like:

```
function gaCheckout(step) {
      ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {'step': step});
       ga('send', 'event', 'checkout', 'dummy', 'dummy');
}
function gaCheckoutOption(step, value) {
    ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout_option', {'step': step, 'option': value});
    ga('send', 'event', 'checkout_option', 'dummy', 'dummy'); 
}
```

When the user selects an option you call the `gaCheckoutOption` and when clicks the continue button the `gaCheckout` is called. If the user scrolls up and change some previous step value, only the `gaCheckoutOption` is needed.

Comment: First - thanks a lot for your answer. But a have a doubt about the 1st point: I've checked the google-analytics debug messages in console, and I only can see the one **last** action set with *ec:setAction*, so I suppose that ga('ec:setAction') - calls overwrites previous calls until I sent data with event or pageview...  maybe I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It is posible because, as far I know, the ec:setActions calls are stacked and maybe only last action is shown but I'm not sure now. I cannot test it right now but I thought ga send all data together, have you tested if data appears in your funnel? Anyway I recommend sending one event every time you make an ec:setAction.. let me know any progress!

Comment: yes, I thought the same, and I was puzzled when I discovered such behaviour; of couse, after that I've splitted ga-data sending by one setAction per request, but I'm still not sure if it was nessessary :)  but I dont think there are any reason not to trust ga debug messages... if request details contains only one setAction - I don think that the encoded request could contain something different :)